# How can I improve my ratings?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

So I made my first game - it was a Space Adventure game and I called it EVE. When I released it I waited until all of my bugs had been fixed and then released it immediately. However, when the ratings came in from the press the game was universally disliked:

[image]

What can I do to improve the ratings for my games?

Comment: What did you focus on in the dev stages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to improve the ratings, you can do one of the following:

- Selecting a good combo between genre and type, for example fantasy + RPG will get you a bonus in ratings
- Set the sliders at the right level and for medium games and larger, you need to assign staff with the right competencies. This is actually quite complicated and would require a section on its own, a very detailed description can be found [here](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Game_Development)
- Hire more/Train your developers, this will allow them to be more productive during development phase. This option is unlocked before you make enough money to move to a larger office
- Wait for the game to be totally debugged before to click on finish. You just need to wait until the number of bugs goes to 0
- Spend money on research and game engines so that you can use better options
- Focus on the important parts of the games, for example for RPG, you need better story, dialogues, world and decent graphics. Do not set things like sound to minimum or you risk getting the odd review telling you that you could have spent more time on sound
- Later on, starting with medium games, you need to allocate the right person to the right part of the development or you risk not getting enough points in this part

One mistake many people do in their first games is to do too many game engines, the most important factor in getting high reviews is actually to train your staff and specialize them in order to assign them to the correct tasks in medium games and larger. Game engines should be developed only when you have done many research options that you want to incorporate (do not develop 1 game engine to incorporate a single research option)

Comment: One thing you missed is that in this game, the player is always competing *against their previous high score* (a value which is not shown to the player). If you make two excellent games in a row, the second one will have a poor rating - because it doesn't exceed the previous game's score. You get a higher game score by doing the things in the bullet points, but by itself this is not a guarantee of good **review** scores.

Comment: @Tacroy: It is true, this is why training is the most important thing to get good reviews. Do you want to edit the reply ?